# Escape single quote inside single quote inside double quote

Tags: bash, quotes, double-quotes, single-quotes

I'm trying to run a query on a remote server from by bash script. Problem is, I have to use single quotes inside of the query which already has surrounding single quotes.

My code:

```
# note: $line has ` in it, as this is a SQL query
ssh server "mysql --defaults-extra-file=$SQL_CREDS_FILE $R_DB $t -e '$line INTO OUTFILE \"\'\"$DIR/$tbl_count.csv\"\'\" FIELDS TERMINATED BY \"\'\",\"\'\" ENCLOSED BY \"\'\"\"\'\" LINES TERMINATED BY \"\'\"\n\"\'\"'"
```

The error I'm seeing upon running this code:

```
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Example of working MYSQL query:

```
mysql -u user -pPassword database -e 'select `id`,`title`,`name`,`description`,`icon`,`creation_date` as `created_at`,`mutation_date` as `created_at` from achievement;'
```

Comment: Are the ` characters escaped in `$line`? I think it might solve the issue.

Comment: @vicraj Tried that with `\\`` but unfortunately no luck there.

Comment: The `$(...)` around the command is wrong, unless you specifically expect the `ssh` command to return a command which should be evaluated locally (which in turn seems like a very risky construct; but really, I can't believe that's what you want here).

Comment: I tried to post an answer but it's really hard to guess what command you expect to actually end up executing. Could you please [edit] your question to show the exact command which should execute, and perhaps what you expect all these variables to be set to.

Comment: Inside single quotes, `\'` is just a literal backslash followed by a terminating single quote. Are you trying to get ...`INTO OUTFILE '$DIR/$tbl_count.csv' FIELDS`... as the result here?

Comment: @tripleee Exactly, the result should be `'$DIR/$tabl_count.csv'`, I'll remove the `$(...)` as that is indeed not the desired result.

Comment: Can you post the code without escaping? Something that _works_. Ex. the mysql command that works but executed not in a one-liner but by typing into ssh session. Or the `INTO OUTFILE` part that works when typed inside mysql session.

Comment: @KamilCuk Updated the post with an example of the MYSQL query I'm running.

Comment: The query is not at all the same as in the first code snipped? You need to post something others can work with. Ex. I have mysql up and running on a remote ssh server. What should I do, to test if your command works or not? Please try to create an [MCVE] for others to test. You want the variables `$line` `$DIR` and `$tbl_count` and `$SQL_CREDS_FILE $R_DB $t` to be expanded on the host side or on the remote ssh side?

Comment: @KamilCuk That's because the query is inside a file which is read, the query itself is inside of the `$line` variable. I also excluded the `INTO OUTFILE` part

Comment: The edit helps, but many parts of the canned query are still not clear from the example you added. What *exactly* should you end up executing on the remote server with this `ssh` command?

Comment: @tripleee Please see my answer, I was able to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest workaround is to use a context where you don't quote the expression at all.

Using a here document will tie up the standard input of `ssh`, but in this case it seems acceptable (or perhaps even desirable).

```sh
ssh server <<____HERE
# Guessing $R_DB contains "database"
# Guessing $t contains your credentials ...?
# Guessing $DIR contains a directory name
# Guessing $tbl_count contains a file name
# Guessing $line contains your actual query  
mysql "$R_DB" $t -e "${line//\`/\\\`} INTO OUTFILE '$DIR/$tbl_count.csv'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"
____HERE
```

The parameter expansion `` ${line//\`/\\\`} `` is a Bash-only feature so this depends on the remote shell being Bash.

Answer (score 1):

After the comment by @KamilCuk it got me thinking about the escape characters and running the code without the SSH.

I have rewritten the code to only contain `"` or `'` which results in:

```
ssh server "mysql --defaults-extra-file=$SQL_CREDS_FILE $R_DB -e \"$line INTO OUTFILE '$DIR/$tbl_count.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'\"" < /dev/null
```

Also removing the ` helped, as anything between that character will be executed as a command.